# CSS Hover-Animation to 'Still'?

Tags: html, css

The following code lets my button glow in an animation on hover.

Now im trying to make it work without the need to hover over it.

Usually, i would go for .class:hover and try to edit something there. But a bit confused on this one, since there is only 1 line in that attribute.

Thanks for any help

```
.drts-bs-btn-outline-primary {
    width: 220px;
    height: 50px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: #fff;
    background: #111;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.drts-bs-btn-outline-primary:before {
    content: '';
    background: linear-gradient(45deg, #ff0000, #ff7300, #fffb00, #48ff00, #00ffd5, #002bff, #7a00ff, #ff00c8, #ff0000);
    position: absolute;
    top: -2px;
    left:-2px;
    background-size: 400%;
    z-index: -1;
    filter: blur(5px);
    width: calc(100% + 4px);
    height: calc(100% + 4px);
    animation: glowing 20s linear infinite;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.drts-bs-btn-outline-primary:active {
    color: #000
}

.drts-bs-btn-outline-primary:active:after {
    background: transparent;
}

.drts-bs-btn-outline-primary:hover:before {
    opacity: 1;
}

.drts-bs-btn-outline-primary:after {
    z-index: -1;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #111;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

@keyframes glowing {
    0% { background-position: 0 0; }
    50% { background-position: 400% 0; }
    100% { background-position: 0 0; }
}
```

Comment: Having a working snippet with HTML included would make this a better question perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

To make the button glow even when not hovering, you should move the contents of `.drts-bs-btn-outline-primary:hover:before` (note the :hover) into `.drts-bs-btn-outline-primary:before` (note the lack of :hover). In other words, you should delete the `opacity: 0;` line.

Answer (score 0):

The only reason it wasn't working was because the animation was set to `opacity: 0;` until it was hovered. With the code below you won't need the `.drts-bs-btn-outline-primary:hover:before { opacity: 1; }` css rule anymore

```css
.drts-bs-btn-outline-primary {
    width: 220px;
    height: 50px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: #fff;
    background: #111;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
.drts-bs-btn-outline-primary:before {
    content: '';
    background: linear-gradient(45deg, #ff0000, #ff7300, #fffb00, #48ff00, #00ffd5, #002bff, #7a00ff, #ff00c8, #ff0000);
    position: absolute;
    top: -2px;
    left:-2px;
    background-size: 400%;
    z-index: -1;
    filter: blur(5px);
    width: calc(100% + 4px);
    height: calc(100% + 4px);
    animation: glowing 20s linear infinite;
    transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.drts-bs-btn-outline-primary:active {
    color: #000
}

.drts-bs-btn-outline-primary:active:after {
    background: transparent;
}

.drts-bs-btn-outline-primary:after {
    z-index: -1;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #111;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

@keyframes glowing {
    0% { background-position: 0 0; }
    50% { background-position: 400% 0; }
    100% { background-position: 0 0; }
}

/* GLOWING TEXT STARTS HERE */
.amazing-h2 {
  animation: amazing-h2-glow 1s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}

@-webkit-keyframes amazing-h2-glow {
  from {
    text-shadow: 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 20px #fff, 0 0 30px #e60073, 0 0 40px #e60073, 0 0 50px #e60073, 0 0 60px #e60073, 0 0 70px #e60073;
  }
  to {
    text-shadow: 0 0 20px #fff, 0 0 30px #ff4da6, 0 0 40px #ff4da6, 0 0 50px #ff4da6, 0 0 60px #ff4da6, 0 0 70px #ff4da6, 0 0 80px #ff4da6;
  }
}
```

```html
<button class="drts-bs-btn-outline-primary">Click Me!</button>

<br><br>

<h2 class="amazing-h2">This is an H2</h2>
```

Comment: Thank you! Appreciate it

Also, is there a way to use that animation on plain text?

Been trying around but without any success

Again, much thanks

Comment: I would approach the text slightly differently, I've added the code to get you started but you'll have to adjust the colours to get it looking the way your hoping for!